# Security policy error importing matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation

After installing matplotlib. I am getting this error while using this command :

```
$ import matplotlib
```

```
import-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PS` @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408.
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `import matplotlib` not from the python shell, but from the system shell. The error you are seeing is from the `import` command, which according to `man import` saves a portion of a screen to an image. This also happens if you execute a script by calling it without putting a shabang on the first line (like `#!/usr/bin/env python3`)

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me if I run `import` from the shell. Demonstration:

```sh
$ import
import-im6.q16: missing an image filename `import' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/1289.
```

[This `askubuntu` question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181762/imagemagickconvert-im6-q16-no-images-defined) tells me that `import` is a built-in ImageMagick command.

### Solution

You first have to start a Python interactive prompt:

```py
python
>>> import matplotlib
```

Comment: When you write a Python script that you would like to run from a shell, you should start it with `#!/bin/env python` so that your shell uses the Python interpreter when you run it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you do `import matplotlib`

The problem can be solved with just one of the following solutions.

1. If you're using the Python interpreter, the one from the command line, then this shouldn't happen because you are simply importing the module.
2. If you wrote the line of code in a Python file, suppose we call the file *myfile.py*, and you're trying to execute it on the command line like `./myfile.py` then it's wrong because you have to write on the command line `python myfile.py` or `python3 myfile.py`, if you're using Python3
3. You can simply specify the python interpreter on your file by adding at the first line of the file `#!/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/python` and then on the command line you can simply run your file like a bash file `./myfile.py`

Comment: I can confirm that this is a general problem that can happen with any python script, and that doing 2 or 3 fixes the problem. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

See the other, older answers. They are very good.

Another possible reason: It might be a cut-and-paste-from-clipboard  error.

You may have blanks before your `#!/usr/bin/env python3` line, and at the beginning of all following lines. Thus your script is still a valid python-script but the shell cannot interpret the `#!/usr/bin/env python3` line. It thus reads your script as a bash script.

It might help to remove the whitespace; or call the script with
`python3 myscript.py`